# Visual Studio 2015 Add Class, Error: "object already exists"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, object, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

Other similar but to my knowledge non-related questions:

[A file or folder with the name '' already exists Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402950/a-file-or-folder-with-the-name-already-exists-visual-studio-2012)

[ATL simple object wizard - "Object Xxx already exists" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636975/atl-simple-object-wizard-object-xxx-already-exists-error)

**The error:**
I try to add a simple class 
[image]
 and then proceed to the wizard where I get the following Error][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzyZj.png): 
[image]
"Object already exists".
I can't add the class "MainGame" (and a few other names) to any project, not even if I create a new project

**How to recreate said bug/error:**
The error occured when I deleted a Release folder I'd accidentally copied over from a project in another solution. All now non-functional class names are derived from the object files within that Release folder.

**Solution:**
I have no solution.

**My questions are:**
Have anyone else had this or a similar issue?
If so, have you solved it and what is your solution?

I am open to all suggestions and while this 'bug' isn't making programming impossible it is quite annoying not being able to use frequently used class names.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ATL simple object wizard - "Object Xxx already exists" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636975/atl-simple-object-wizard-object-xxx-already-exists-error)

Comment: Make sure you don't have any classes called `MainGame` defined in other Source Files

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yeah, also saw that.

I think I have created a C++ class, decided I don’t like it, reverted changes using github app. But the name was good, so I tried creating same class again. Saw the exact same error as you’re having.

The name polluted the sqlite database. And because I had that VC.db in my .gitignore, git hasn't reverted that.

To fix, quit visual studio, delete the file $(SolutionName).VC.db in your $(SolutionDir) folder, restart visual studio, clean and rebuild your project[s].

**Update:** Modern versions of Visual Studio usually keep these SQLite databases inside `.vs` folder under $(SolutionDir).

Comment: Glad that worked for you, but unfortunately I've tried it earlier and tried it again but to no avail. I still have the same error. But since it might work for someone else I'll upvote you.

Comment: @ShadowNinja Just in case, do you have VS2015 Update 3 installed? Press Help->About, mine says "Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3"

Comment: @ShadowNinja Well, couple more things to try, then. 1. Ensure you don’t have MainGame.cpp / .h / .hpp file anywhere under your project directory. 2. Ensure you don’t have MainGame class or namespace anywhere in your project, if you’re using C++ keyboard scheme, that’s Ctrl+Shift+F. 3. Close the IDE and manually remove the temporary folders (Debug/Release/x64). I remember when cleaning the solution, sometimes the IDE failed to remove some .obj files which caused problems.

Comment: Was pulling my hair out over this one. Even procmon didn't help. Thanks for this.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem with a VS 2017 project.  I opened, rebuilt, and closed the project about 5 times and the error went away...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like VS caching issue. I too faced this issue and your solution did not work for me either.

What I did is add a Class with different name lets say `MainGame1` and then it allowed me to add. Then I just renamed the Class name, CPP and header file name to my like.

Answer (score 1):

Manually create example.h and example.cpp in Solution directory then:

`Add` -> `Existing Item...` -> add created file to your project.

This trick work for me after clean $(SolutionName).VC.db file.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you don't have any .h .cpp in your project, make sure you don't have "MainGame" declaration or definition in any other .h .cpp file as an inner class either.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem. To solve it using your example names:

1. Manually create an empty "MainGame.h" and "MainGame.cpp."
   (...probably doesn't have to be empty.)
2. Add both files to your project.
3. Then finally remove both files from your project, deleting the files from disk.

After that, it will let you use that name when creating a new class with the class wizard. It's neither an elegant solution nor a complete one. It will let you get past that one problem. I suspect I'll run into it again with other names that aren't getting cleaned out of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue, which was solved by cleaning up the visual studio cache.

Just close VS, clean up the files in (for VS2015) %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp

, and restart VS. It should go back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the existing *.sln when you launch VS again it will allow without any error.