# How to create 2 classes with the same name in two separate projects in one solution?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've got one solution right now, and it contains 3 separate projects. One project is a game engine, which I have given its own namespace and am now using in my other two projects. The other two projects are simple games that I have made as prototypes.

I am now working on my second game, and I am trying to add a class to the project that already exists in the first game. The second game is in no way dependent on the first game except for the fact that they use the same engine. Visual Studio will not let me add another class, it simply says "Object 'Bullet' already exists". Is there a way for me to force visual studio to make it anyway?

There is no reason for these to be conflicting, as far as I can tell, because they are separate projects with separate classes.

Comment: I think you need to supply some more details. For me, adding a class in Visual Studio consists of creating a source file and writing the class code. VS has never protested about some object allegedly existing.

Comment: I'm not sure what else I could supply. They share a debug folder but the only thing in there is my engine lib, .exes, and the glew and sdl2 .dll's.

Comment: Why do you need to create two separate classes? Why not include class implementation files to the both projects?

Comment: They use the class differently; it's not a class I want to be a part of my engine.

Comment: Perhaps detail the steps you use to reproduce the problem? Like a cookbook recipe with number points, 1, 2, 3...

Comment: I think I found what's wrong and just posted an answer; couldn't find an instance of someone having the issue with a c++ class but it seems like it's a bug with visual studio. It would seem to me that the easiest way to reproduce the bug would be to make 2 projects and then try to add the same class to both of them. If that doesn't reproduce the issue, then I don't know what would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ATL simple object wizard - "Object Xxx already exists" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636975/atl-simple-object-wizard-object-xxx-already-exists-error)

Not exactly my problem, but basically. Seems to be an issue with visual studio thinking that the object exists because it has it cached that I created it. Made a Bullet2 and then renamed it and it worked fine.